# Deface issue with virtual_path in engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deface

I'm working on an rails app with several mountable engines. I use the deface gem to override some part of views but I'm having some issues to update some of them.

I don't know if it's a problem or a mistake that I'm making but it seems like `deface` has some problems to trigger when you have a partial inside the `layout` file (I'm also working with mountable engines)

Let me explain with an example. I have the following code on my app on application.html.erb file.

```
<!-- some code -->
<div class = "container">
    <header class="masthead">
       <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
    </header>

<!-- some more code -->
```

And on the navbar.html.erb file I have:

```
<!-- some code -->
<li data-dat-hook='main_nav' class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to 'Home', dat.root_path, class: "nav-link" %> 
</li>
<!-- some more code -->
```

What will trigger deface is the `data-dat-hook`.

Defined in the proper file, in the proper place:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "dat/shared/_navbar",
                 :name => "add_contacts_link_to_main_nav",
                 :insert_after => "[data-dat-hook='main_nav']",
                 :partial => "overrides/analyses_link",
                 :namespaced => true)
```

Deface seems to not even realize the existence of this virtual path. I don't know why... If I move the code from the partial to the layout file (and update the virtual path) things work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer...

It was a issue because of the namespace.

I have defined a shortcut on the engine file like this:

```
paths["app/views"] << "app/views/dat"
```

(by the way, my namespace is "dat")

Just to avoid having to add this namespace everywhere when calling for view. Well, it seems like 'deface' didn't understood that.

So, as soon as I updated the render code on my application file to include the namespace path everything start working...

```
<%= render "dat/shared/navbar" %>
```

And that's it.